# Why does the optical rotation prefix differ for glyceraldehyde and glyceric acid when both rotate polarised light in the same direction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

When both glyceraldehyde and glyceric acid rotate the plane-polarised light in the same direction, why is glyceraldehyde assigned as D(+) and glyceric acid assigned as D(-)?

The first image shows the chemical conversion of D(+)-glyceraldehyde to D(-)-glyceric acid. The second image shows the rule for assigning absolute configuration.

[image]

Comment: Well, there are only two configurations, no matter what do you call them.

Comment: ᴅ-(+)-Glyceraldehyde and ᴅ-(−)-glyceric acid do not rotate polarised light in the same direction.

Comment: @Loong  kindly elaborate . I have assigned priorities to groups around the carbons in both the compounds . Kindly correct if I have assigned in a wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D and L are determined by arbitrary rules that you've referenced. (+) and (-) specify the net optical rotation of plane polarized light by a sample. There is no way for a human to determine (+) and (-) just by looking at a molecule. It is fixed, but it is whatever it is.

There is no relationship between the D/L and +/- designation across all substances. However, for a given substance the relationship is fixed.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But as far as I know D,L is different from d,l.  D,L refers to Relative configuration whereas d,l or +,-  or R,Srefers to absolute configuration. I want to know why both glyceraldehyde and glyceric acid are assigned different absolute configurations when both rotate plane polarised light in same direction or is there a difference between +,- and R,S. kindly correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

The D/L designation is fully irrelevant, as Zhe’s answer points out. The same is true for R/S or any other minor standards that are based on the molecular structure alone. Whether a molecule rotates polarised light to the right ($+$) or to the left ($-$) can be determined only by experiment.

There is a clear discrepancy between your two statements:

- > D-(+)-glyceraldehyde and D-(−)-glyceric acid

  and
- > rotate the plane of light in the same direction

Both cannot be true; either the naming was incorrect and D-glyceric acid should be called D-(+)-glyceric acid or the measurement result was in fact the opposite, i.e. the polarisation is opposite. The answer by Zhe and Loong’s comment assume the latter. However, checking Sigma-Aldrich’s webpage, I get told that the optical activity of D-glyceric acid is positive by the sign convention. That would mean that it should be correctly labelled as D-(+)-glyceric acid. The caveat being that the disodium salt was measured.

The dispute will only be settled by confirmation experiment or by literature citations. In any case, one statement will fall. Either the designation is correct; then they polarise in different directions. Or the result you state is correct, then glyceric acid’s designation is wrong.

Comment: I think as your said, only R and S nomenclature of a compound can be assigned theoretically by looking at the compound. But, + and- can be assigned only after experimentally determining the compound's optical activity using a polarimeter. This is what I have understood. Thank you your answer

Comment: @Shakti I didn’t explicitly mention it but *all* stereochemical descriptors aside from ($+$) and ($-$) are determined based on the structure. Whether it is (*R* / *S*), (a*R* / a*S*), d/l, D/L (if there even is a difference between the two), *syn/anti*, *cis/trans* or (*E* / *Z*). If I forgot to mention one, it was probably oversight. So none of these correlate in any way with the direction of rotation of polarised light, and there is no way to predict the polarisation based only on knowing the structure.

Comment: Thank you Jan......so basically these configurations are only to say the spatial arrangement of groups around a chiral carbon but cannot determine the optical rotation . Am I right ?

Comment: @Shakti Yes. You cannot even infer that the optical rotation will be the same as in a sample compound after a reaction that does not touch a single chiral centre. Source: it happened to me after opening a lactone. (I have not seen any examples but I do not deem it impossible for the sign of optical rotation to change upon something as simple as alcohol methylation without that inducing any severe conformational change.)